# How do I get `cProfile.run` to log time consumed by calls to `str`?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, profiling

I'm trying to analyze the performance of some code that makes a lot of calls to `str` to see if I can benefit from substituting other approaches for the use of `str`, but I can't get `cProfile.run` to show me how much time calls to `str` are consuming.

For example if I test the (nonsense) code

```
def foo(n):
    x = ''
    for i in range(n):
        x += str(n)
        x = str(len(str(n)))
```

with `cProfile.run('foo(1000000)')` I get no mention of the many calls that must have been made to `str`:

```
         1000004 function calls in 1.163 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.163    1.163 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    1.046    1.046    1.163    1.163 example.py:172(foo)
  1000000    0.081    0.000    0.081    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.036    0.036    0.036    0.036 {range}
```

How do I get `cProfile.run` to show statistics for calls to `str`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it does not display the calls to `str`, but you can easily bypass this behavior (for the sake of profiling only), by overriding the builtin `str`.

Simply add this code at the top of your script, or before invoking `cProfile`:

```
orig_str = __builtin__.str
def mystr(*a, **kw): return orig_str(*a, **kw)
__builtin__.str = mystr
```

This might not be completely compatible with the original code (e.g. if you have places in your code which do things like `if type(x) == str`), but hopefully it would work in your case.